# How do I use django GenericForeignKeys?

Tags: python, django, relationship

I have the following two models:

```py
class URLResource(models.Model):
    class ResourceType(models.TextChoices):
        VID = 'VID', _('Video')
        DOC = 'DOC', _('Document')
    
    resource_type = models.CharField(
            choices=ResourceType.choices,
            default=ResourceType.UNK,
            max_length=3)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=280, null=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'URLResource {self.resource_type}: {self.title} URL: {self.url}'


class Record(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
            ...)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)

    # <resource>: I want to point to a resource somehow

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Record {{ User: {self.user}, Resource:  }}'
```

My use case is such that a lot of users can create `Records` and list them, but since the underlying `URLResource` is going to be same, I thought I could use many-to-one relationship from Records-to-URLResource so the underlying resources would remain the same. However, even though I have only one type of resource now i.e. `URLResource`, I also want to roll out other resources like `VideoResource`, `PhysicalResource` etc. Clearly, I can't simply use the many-to-one relationship. So, I figured I could use Django's [contenttype framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), but I still can't get things to work.

I want to be able to do atleast these two things:

1. When creating a `Record`, I can easily assign it a `URLResource` (or any other `Resource`) **(but only one resource)**.
2. I can easily access the `URLResource` fields. For example like `Record.objects.get(user=x).resource.resource_type`.

Comment: As an advice don't use the content type framework (It makes it difficult to have referential integrity). Just have an extra model let's say with the name `Resource` and have all other types of resource models have a one to one relationship with this one. (In fact the content type framework would also do something similar but that would be much more hacky and would not actually use foreign keys to respective tables)

Comment: Actually that's how my implementation was until I wondered if there might be a better way to do it i.e. I could just go and query `<record_object>.resource.field`, than `<record>.x-resource.field` over the range of all possible resource types.

Comment: Perhaps try using a property that would give you the resource instance of the correct  model?